# Openings for pawn storms

Tags: opening, planning

I am a weak player and I always will be. After completing the opening I have no idea what to do and, since a bad plan is better than no plan, I decided to do this from now on in every game:

1. wait for my opponent to castle;
2. castle in the opposite side;
3. start a pawn storm.

My usual opponents are even weaker than me, so I really think it can work, and I expect it to be more enjoyable than just wait for a tactical mistake.
My question is... what kind of opening repertoire is most suited to implement my plan?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable plan. Anyway, if your opponents are weaker than you, pretty much anything should work. One question, though. What do you do if your opponent won't castle?

Comment: I don't know... as I said, this is the first plan I'll use.

Comment: Where's the fun in doing the same thing in every game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your opponent is most likely to castle short, you have to choose lines where long castling (for you) is reasonable.

With white I would suggest `1. e4`, and against `1... e5` the Center Game `1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. Qxd4 Nc6 4. Qe3`.

```
[Title "Center Game"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. Qxd4 Nc6 4. Qe3
```

Against `1... c5` you can play the Open Sicilian (`2. Nf3` followed by `3. d4`).

Against other black defenses you can find lines with long castling as well.

With black it's more difficult. You could try the French Winawer

```
[Title "French Winawer"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Bb4
```

against `1. e4` and the Albin Countergambit

```
[Title "Albin Countergambit"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 d4
```

against `1. d4`.